# question about width of an absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, absolute

I'm new in CSS. I don't understand if a display: absolute; element for instance a , is still consider child of its parent or not (for its out of the flow)?

For example:

```
**HTML**

<div class="container">
   <div class="my_div">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
       In sit amet nibh et arcu gravida tincidunt. Nam dignissim elit
       vitae erat porta, at efficitur lacus consequat. Sed molestie,
       mi a efficitur elementum, lacus metus hendrerit libero, posuere
       ultricies urna libero nec quam. 
   </div>
</div>


**CSS**

.container div {
   width: 50%;
}

.my_div {
   position: absolute;
}
```

without the position: absolute; my_div width is equal to the 50% width of the container . But after the setting position: absolute; I don't understand what actually happen to the my_div width, is still referring to the CSS .container div{} rule or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"parent-child relationship"* doesn't really change (so technically it'll still be a child thereof, which you can see reflected in the DOM), but the *"(document) flow"* does indeed change.

Once you use `position: absolute;` the element is removed from the normal document flow, which does affect the effect many properties have (as you've likely noticed).

---

Since you mentioned being new to CSS, i should make sure you're aware that 90%
of the time, when online tutorials (or books) suggest using properties such as `position` and `float`, they are likely to be leading you down an outdated and/or misguided path.

Nowadays we have things like flexbox (`display: flex`) and grid (`display: grid`) which make the vast majority of layout challenges (which used to be a pain to understand/create) totally simple.

Answer (score -1):

It is still a child of the parent, but it is also outside the flow. Giving the parent `position: relative;` will allow certain properties on the child (like `top`, etc) to still act relative to the parent. Usually absolutely positioned elements require explicit `height` and `width` declarations, but it depends on what you are trying to do...